# How to get Hadoop output to Text, Text format?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a file containing data in the format: 
director movie

I'm using hadoop and Java to process it.

It's pretty basic to count the number of movies for every director, but how can I modify the code to get  something like this:

director movie1 movie2 movie3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do.

```
@Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String movies;

        for (Text value : values) {
            movies += value.toString() + " ";
        }
        context.write(key, new Text(movies));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's straightforward from counting the number of movies for every director, high level structure may like this:

```
mapper(file):
    for each (director, movie) in file:
        emit(director, movie)

reducer(director, movies):
    movielist = []
    for each movie in movies:
        movielist.add(movie)
    emit(director, movielist)
```